# Need help with MAAS

Tags: networking, server, maas

I'm new to MAAS and I'm trying to setup my first cluster.
My cluster will consist of 3 servers:

1x Master [M001] (Web UI, DHCP, PXE boot etc.)
2x Node [Fancy-Cord & Polished-Ghost] (MySQL, Apache webserver etc.)

Yet, I cannot seem to figure out how it works.
I have 2 NICs on M001, 1 which is connected to my home network (eth0), and 1 connected to a switch (SW015) for the nodes (eth1).

when I type `ifconfig` in the console, it only showsup eth0...

[image: My configuration of the cluster interface]

When I bootup one of my (should become) nodes (Fancy-cord of Polished-Ghost, doesn't matter), and have them go for the PXE, it shows:
`pxe-e18 server response timeout`

also, when I attach a laptop (with windows 8.1) to SW015, it seems DHCP doesn't do anything, how do I fix this? (since I think solving the DHCP issue might help me solve the issue of PXE)

If you need additional information, feel free to ask, but don't expect me to be a wizard knowing where everything is found (I'm VERY new to MAAS)

UPDATE1:
This is how my networks tab looks like (http://M001/MAAS/networks/Cluster/edit/)
[image: This is how my networks tab looks like]

UPDATE2:
Managed to get a littlebit of progress (I guess)
Instead of `pxe-e18 server response timeout` I now get `pxe-e51: No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to have it to work!

I had to go in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: I was just about to type this up as an answer.  (For multi-homed cluster controllers you have to manually edit the interfaces file and then reboot.)